# How use two version dependency version in maven?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I want to set some dependency with two versions:

```
<vesion>1.5-SNAPTSHOT,1.5</version>
```

I want that maven always use 1.5-SNAPTSHOT, and only when it does not exist, it must use 1.5. (not vice versa).

How write proper configuration with insurance that SNAPSHOT version is used first?

Comment: Why do you need such thing? Apart from being possible?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a "Stable" 1.5 version, there's no need to use SNAPSHOT. Use SNAPSHOT when the version was not released yet and still under development.

When you use SNAPSHOT, Maven still looking for a new version every time you build your project. But when you use a "stable" version (withou -SNAPSHOT), Maven won't be looking for a new version anymore.

So, I guess that (in this case) you better use SNAPSHOT.